# Validating mathematical operators in simple calculator

Tags: java

I need help validating operators in a calculator program, the user is asked for two numbers and an operator i.e. 3 + 2 but I cannot validate the operator. If the user enters a +, -, *, or / operator it tells me this input is invalid when it should be fine. Validating the first number is fine there's no problem there. Can someone please help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int int1;
        String operator;
        int int2;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter first number: ");

        while(!scan.hasNextInt()){
            scan.next();
            System.err.print("Invalid input please enter a number: ");
        }

        int1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter operator (+, -, *, /): ");

        while(!scan.equals("+") && !scan.equals("-") && !scan.equals("*") && !scan.equals("/")){
                scan.next();
            System.err.print("Invalid input please enter a valid operator (+, -, *, /");
        }

        operator = scan.next();

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");


        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're comparing a `Scanner` with the `String`s. They're different types, so they're never going to be equal.

Comment: Use `scan.hasNext()` and `scan.next()` to get the next String input, the same way you are using it for integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the output of scan.next(), not of scan

```
    System.out.println("Enter operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    operator = scan.next();
    while(!operator.equals("+") && !operator.equals("-") && !operator.equals("*") && !operator.equals("/")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input please enter a valid operator (+, -, *, /");
        operator = scan.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!scan.hasNext("[*+/-]")){
```

use this code instead of `while(!scan.equals("+") && !scan.equals("-") && !scan.equals("*") && !scan.equals("/")){`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going with a char type as we are only reading a single letter. This should do:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = reader.nextChar();

if(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '/' || c == '*') {
      //operation
}else{
      //Error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` does not implement `equals()`, so you're doing identity comparisons, and `Scanner` is never equal to a String literal.

Use this loop instead:

```
while(!scan.hasNext("[+\\-*/]")){
```

*FYI:* Your "skip" calls should be `scan.nextLine()`, not `scan.next()`, so all input on the line is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here:

```
while(!scan.equals("+") && !scan.equals("-") && !scan.equals("*") && !scan.equals("/"))
```

The `equals()` method performs a comparison between the object calling the method and the object passed into the method as an argument.

For example the statement `if (myString.equals(anotherString))`, compares the `myString` object with the `anotherString` object.

Since `scan` is the name of your `Scanner`, when you write `scan.equals("+")` you are comparing to see if your `Scanner` is equal to the `String` "+". Which is impossible!

The easiest solution to understand would be to just put the next `String` entered by the user into a variable and then check that variable contains an operator.

**Example**

```
String operator = scan.next();

while(!operator.equals("+") && !operator.equals("-") 
      && !operator.equals("*") && !operator.equals("/")) {   
    operator = scan.next();
    System.err.print("Invalid input please enter a valid operator (+, -, *, /");
}
```

The other answers will help you to improve your code more than this. I just thought I would show you the smallest change you could make to your code to fix your specific problem. :)